# Deallocate and resize VM's in-parallel via azure cli

Tags: bash, azure-cli

I want to perform resize operation on selected VM's from one resource group from azure cli. De-allocation operation running in sequence due to which it takes longer time.

If I want to use `no-wait` or `&` or `sleep` as I don't know how long each VM deallocation my take 60s or 100s may be more.
I get error message `Previous stop-deallocate operation on vm did not complete yet` as immediately after it tries to perform resize. I want to run the VM deallocation in parallel
VM1 stop, VM2 stop, VM3 stop so on... by sending parallel de-allocation command I can minimize overall execution time.

As long as stop operation done on each VM, then resize operation should take place. How Can I make that command wait till the time last command (VM deallocation) is successful.

```
#!/bin/bash
rg=westeurope-v02
vm=$p
filename='az.txt'
vmsku=standard_E16ds_v4

echo "\nDeallocating VM"
while read p; do
vmstate=$(az vm get-instance-view --name $p --resource-group $rg --query instanceView.statuses\[1] --output table | grep "VM running" | awk '{print $3" "$4}')
if [[ ${vmstate} == "VM running" ]]; then
    echo "VM $p is running ...attempting deallocate now !!"
    deallocate=$(az vm deallocate -g $rg -n $p) &
    echo "VM $p is $vmstate" 
    if [[ ${vmstate} == "VM deallocated" ]] || [[ ${vmstate} == "VM stopped" ]]; then
        echo "$vm has deallocated successfully..."
        echo "--------------------------------------------------"
    else    
        echo "$vm is still deallocating..."
        echo "waiting for 30 seconds"
        sleep 30 # want to make some condition here so that resizing should not go successfully
    fi
fi
done < $filename

echo "\n Resizing VM \n"
while read p; do
echo "Attempting to resize VM to $vmsku" 
vmsku=$(az vm resize --resource-group $rg  --name $p --size "Standard_E16ds_v4")
vmsize=$(az vm show -g $rg -n $p --query hardwareProfile.vmSize -o tsv)
if [[ ${vmsize} == "standard_E16ds_v4" ]]; then
    echo "VM class successfully converted to $vmsize for $p"
fi
done < $filename

echo "\n Starting VM post SKU conversion\n"
while read p; do
echo "Attempting to start $p with $vmsize"
postconv=$(az vm start -g $rg -n $p)
if [[ ${postconv} -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "VM $p started successfully...\n"
else
    echo "VM $p failed to start\n"
fi
done < $filename
```

Comment: You can run this in a single loop with `(deallocate ... ; resize ...; start )&` within loop body.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg Are you referring while loop here?

Comment: Yes. I mean that for each instance you spawn an asynchronous subshell that deallocate the instance, waits for status change, resize the instance and starts it. All the output should go to log file.

Comment: Any more updates on the question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more things you installed in the VM, the more time you need to spend to deallocate it. And I think your purpose is to resize the VM and deallocate the VMs before doing it. So I think you can deallocate all the VMs directly with the parameters `--no-wait`, and then check use a while loop and in the while loop you check the VM status if it's equal to deallocated, if yes, resize the VM, if not, check the next one. If resize all the VM then get out of the while loop.